# Apollo useQuery hook doesn't get update from cache with writeQuery() method. No errors seen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo

After using `useMutation()`, cache gets updated but `useQuery()` in Home component doesn't.

I tried with a different `fetchPolicy`. I can see new posts in Apollo dev tool but the page needs to be updated to see the changes

```
import { FETCH_POSTS_QUERY } from '../utils/graphql';

function Home() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const {
    loading,
    data
  } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY, {
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
  });
...
```

```
import { useMutation } from '@apollo/react-hooks';

import { useForm } from '../utils/hooks';
import { FETCH_POSTS_QUERY } from '../utils/graphql';

function PostForm() {
  const { values, onChange, onSubmit } = useForm(createPostCallback, {
    body: ''
  });

  const [createPost, { error }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {
    variables: values,
    update(proxy, result) {
      const data = proxy.readQuery({
        query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY
      });
      data.getPosts.push(result.data.createPost);
      proxy.writeQuery({ query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY, data });
      values.body = '';
    }
  });

  function createPostCallback() {
    createPost();
  }
...
```

```
...
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { setContext } from 'apollo-link-context';

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:5000'
});

const authLink = setContext(() => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('jwttoken');
  return {
    headers: {
      Authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
    }
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

...
```

I expect seeing the new post without updating the page.

Answer (score 6):

This code snippet solve the problem with frontend refresh when you write the cache with PostForm:

//in Home.js use this:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
const { loading, data } = useQuery(FETCH_POSTS_QUERY);
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        setPosts(data.getPosts);
    }
}, [data]);
```

and in PostForm.js use this:

```
const [createPost, { error }] = useMutation(CREATE_POST_MUTATION, {
    variables: values,
    update(proxy, result) {
        const data = proxy.readQuery({
            query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY
        });
        const new_post = result.data.createPost;
        proxy.writeQuery({
            query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY,
            data: { getPosts: [new_post, ...data.getPosts] }
        });
        values.body = '';
    }
});
```

This solution was not my idea, but one code hero help us :)

Reference Link :https://gist.github.com/josuecatalan/5b8bf73e69d55683ccf237d5d02b5cef

Original Content: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_SdB42DxdQ&list=PLMhAeHCz8S3_pgb-j51QnCEhXNj5oyl8n&index=6

Answer (score 3):

You are modifying the cached data with `push` here:

```
data.getPosts.push(result.data.createPost);
```

and then returning it as is

```
proxy.writeQuery({ query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY, data });
```

as this is javascript and objects are passed by reference the `data` you returned is the same object you received, so apollo doesn't realise it has changed. Try the following:

```
proxy.writeQuery({ query: FETCH_POSTS_QUERY, data: { ...data } });
```

Comment: now it's not updating cache
if I do like this
```javascript
data.getPosts = [result.data.createPost, ...data.getPosts]
```

it's working as previous

Comment: you are still modifying the same `data` object, try to do it as I have written and create new `data`

Comment: I am having the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: The solution is as written in my post. If you aren't able to fix it, you either don't have the same problem as the OP or you are still re-using the cache object. Update cache with a new object, every time.

Answer (score 0):

In my case backend team just rewrote uploaded image file and leaved the old name. So an application UI didn't want to rerender. And I wasted few hours to debug it.
So don't forget to check the data as well.